# jpa with limited tables/ fields compared to actual table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

If i have a database with tons of tables and tons of fields in each of the tables, **BUT** i only need to work with few of the tables, and with few of the fields inside it.

Can i make "scraped" JPA entities and still have hibernate/jpa work with that ?

fx: if i work with a table thats has 10 different fields, but i only need to do "get" on 2 of the fields and never change/update anything - read only

- can i make an entity class that will work tho it only hold 2 of the fields, or do i need to add all the fields for it to work tho 80% is never used/read ?

**the db:**

table name = test

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
|field1|field2|field3|field4|field5|
+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

**the java entity**

```
@Entity
public class test {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
}
```

would that work ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to create Entities for every table, or fields for every column, so your proposed solution should work.

However, there are some legacy tables which can be a bit annoying to, for instance if you have compound primary and foreign keys, but almost everything is doable, as long as you know how to model it with JPA.

Comment: To add to this answer, be sure to mark the entity as `@Immutable` since these are considered read-only to avoid mistakes of changing the data when not intended.

Comment: Note that `@Immutable` is Hibernate-specific, but if you need pure JPA, `@Column(updatable=false, insertable=false, ...)` should do the trick, too